# how to generate access token on Shopify app without session

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I develop a Shopify app and I used cookies based authentication for that.

**sample code**

```
server.use(session({ secure: true, sameSite: 'none' }, server));
server.use(
    createShopifyAuth({
      apiKey: SHOPIFY_API_KEY,
      secret: SHOPIFY_API_SECRET_KEY,
      scopes: ['read_products', 'write_products', 'read_themes', 'write_themes', 'read_script_tags', 'write_script_tags'],
      async afterAuth(ctx) {
        const { shop, accessToken } = ctx.session;
        
        ctx.cookies.set('shopOrigin', shop, {
          httpOnly: false,
          secure: true,
          sameSite: 'none'
        });
        
       // await login(ctx, accessToken, shop);
       // await getScriptTag(ctx, accessToken, shop);
      },
    }),
)
```

Now, my problem is that it doesn't work on some browsers for **cookies** problems.

How can I use **createShopifyAuth** for generating access token without using cookies. if I comment **server.use(session({ secure: true, sameSite: 'none' }, server));** it doesn't work any more.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check the new JWT auth for cookies less authentication into the Shopify app.

[Shopify Wiki Link](https://shopify.dev/tutorials/authenticate-your-app-using-session-tokens)

Comment: I already read that documentation and I didn't understand how can I push scriptTag or generate a billing invoice. that's why I'm strick with this.